# Google Sheet ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder issue with .setrange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

New user here and not versed in code much. Im working on a COVID-19 form for our company and looking for some help with conditional formatting issues. 
SOW: Current we have a google form with simple questions that employees will fill out each day as they arrive, this data is populated on a google sheet.
Each night a google trigger runs that deletes 200 rows of the google sheet for the next days entries, when that script run its messes up my manual conditional formatting, so im trying to run the delete script followed by a script that will apply the conditional formatting to the new sheet each night so everything is ready for the next day.

This is currently what im running that deletes rows each night:

```
***function deleteResponses() {     
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Sheet_ID');     
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];  
sheet.deleteRows(2, 200);  
 };***
```

This is the conditional formatting script ive added to it and trying to run and getting the following error im hoping someone can help me with.

```
**function deleteResponses() {  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Sheet_ID');  
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];  
  sheet.deleteRows(2, 200);  
};  
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Sheet_ID');  
var range = sheet.getRange('C2:C1010');  
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()  
   .whenTextContains('No')  
    .setBackground('#FF0000')  
    *.setRanges('C2:C1010')*  
    .build();  
var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();  
rules.push(rule);  
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);**
```

Im receiving this error.
"Message details
Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder.setRanges. (line 12, file "Code")"

Anyone that could help me, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: NOTE: Line12 is ".setRanges('C2:C1010')"

Comment: Not sure about this but how about `.setRanges(sheet.getRange('C2:C1010'));`

Comment: BTW Do yourself a favor transfer all of the answers for each day to another sheet for viewing purposes and leave the linked sheet alone to collect data.  My experience with linked sheets suggests that the FormApp will just skip over the lines that you deleted as if they were still there (unless that has changed recently) .  If you want to retrieve the data as it's coming in you can us onFormSubmit and `Sheet.appendRow(e.values);`

Comment: Thanks for all the assistance thus far, Ive been able to move forward but now im stuck on my last line of code. Getting a 
**TypeError: sheet.setConditionalFormatRules is not a function (line 16, file "Code")**

`sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);`

Answer (score 1):

Conditional rule ranges, **are plural** and the setRanges takes a list of them. It should be a list of **ranges** and not a list of **A1 notations**.

So you have to build the range from the A1 notation first, and then pass it to the rule builder like:

```js
var range = sheets.getRange("A1:A1010");
var ranges = [range]; // You can add more ranges to the same rule
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule().setRanges(ranges)...
```

**Note:** Notice you are passing in a list of range objects.

---

**References:**

- [setRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#setrangesranges)

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to be clear.  I think @Aerial is correct but I wanted to point out where I think your problem was:

```
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()  
   .whenTextContains('No')  
    .setBackground('#FF0000')  
    *.setRanges('C2:C1010')*  <= Problem is here
    .build();  
var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();  
rules.push(rule);  
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);**
```

As shown in this example in the documentation. Set Ranges requires an array of Ranges not an array of A1 notations or just one A1 notation.  It could take one range such as [range1].

```
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenNumberBetween(1, 10)
    .setBackground("#FF0000")
    .setRanges([rangeOne, rangeTwo])  <= Notice the array of ranges
    .build();
var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules.push(rule);
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
```

[reference to example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#setRanges(Range))

I'd say that many problems here at SO suggest that many programmers rely on their memory of the documentation too much.  I find it better to refer to the documentation regularly so that when I get to the end of writing code for a while I can spend less time debugging it.

Pay particular attention to return types and parameter types.